# Multiple Image Select Marking task in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Take a JSON that contains images and some other data along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a key to your JSON as "count": 0 and show that count on the image when clicked that image.
2. declare a global variable named count:any = 0; and increase this count by 1 when clicked on the image and map this.count value to the
   object's key count
3. Next create an array and push the same item to the array on click of the image who's count value we have just updated in step 2.
4. Next when the image is de-selected, reset global count variable value and apply reset the count values of objects of JSON by
   iterating using a for loop.

please find the [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5oa1h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: what if we are getting JSON data as URL response, in this case we don't have flags for completed, ischecked and count.

Comment: You can still modify the JSON na, first get the JSON data as it is from the URL response and modify it using map like you can add your own keys and values and then continue the same process as explained above

Comment: If you still face any challenges do let me know will show you how to achieve that as well